# How to include another git repo in my own repo like a submodule, but with additional changes/pullrequests merged?

Tags: git, github, ros

I want to add a github repo to my own repo.
However, there is a bug that I need a fix for. For said bug a pullrequest has already been made, but not yet merged (problems with backwards compatibilty that I don't need).

I have been using submodules so far, but I don't know to apply that pullrequest without losing history etc.

I followed this guide:
https://help.github.com/en/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally#modifying-an-inactive-pull-request-locally

But then, I effectively have a complete new branch that only resides in my repo and it doesn't feel right.

Comment: You pull the PR into the submodule, not the superproject. And then merge the pulled branch. Now you have the bugfix in the submodule. The submodule diverged from its upstream, but who cares? If the PR will ever be merged in the upstream you could reconcile your branches with `git pull --force`.

Comment: @phd any reason this is not an answer?

Comment: @phd I think the way you describe is the way to go, however in which repo does my merge commit live then?

Comment: It's not an answer because I didn't care to write one with properly formatted comments. May be I will do it later. The repository **is** the submodule (git is a DVCS and every `.git` directory is a repository by itself). There is nowhere to push so you cannot publish your changes and your collaborators have to repeat the process of pulling and merging. If you want to push the submodule you need to fork the submodule into your own shared repository and push the submodule there. Your collaborators then pull updates from it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, so you have a superproject in the current directory and a submodule in a subdirectory, let's call it `subm`:

```
.
|
`--subm
```

Pull (fetch and merge) the PR into the submodule:

```
cd subm
git fetch origin pull/$id/head:pr-$id
git merge pr-$id
```

I showed `git fetch` and `git merge` separately to stress there is a merge. Actually these commands can be combined into one `git pull origin pull/$id/head`.

Now you have an updated submodule. Unfortunately you cannot push it back to its `origin` so your collaborators have to merge themselves. To work around the problem you need to fork the submodule from its `origin` to a shared repository available to your team. Then you push the merged branch to the fork and all your collaborators pull from it.

When the submodule merges the PR you no longer need the fork. You remove the fork, and you and all collaborators update the submodule using `git pull origin +master`.

On every change in the submodule you need to commit the change in the superproject:

```
cd .. # back to the root of the superproject
git add subm
git commit -m "Update subm"
```